# How can you change the branch on a PR?

Tags: git, github

I made a PR a couple days ago on github, but I accidentally made my changes on the master branch of my fork. Now I can't submit other pull requests because the master branch I have is modified and not in sync with the original projects master branch.

How could it be possible I can move the branch of the PR I made so I can continue creating new branches based off master, and submit new PR requests simultaneously?

Comment: when you say the "master branch of my fork", do you mean you committed your changes to master, or to your fork that you made a PR from?

Comment: Yes, I committed changes to the master branch then submitted it as a PR.

Comment: Are your changes on master in your remote origin, or only in your local master branch?

Comment: The changes are present and committed to my remote origin.

Answer (score 1):

### Situation

Let's assume that you forked jQuery from `git@github.com:jquery/jquery.git`, that you made two commits on your master branch, and that you opened a PR from master.

This would be the current state of affairs.

```
$ git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all -5

* abcd123 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Your commit two
* abcd123 Your commit one
* abcd123 Some jQuery commit
* abcd123 Some jQuery commit      
* abcd123 Some jQuery commit
```

### Response

Here is an approach to changing the PR to another branch.

**First**, create a new branch off of your master.

```
$ git checkout master
$ git checkout -b my-topic-branch
$ git push --set-upstream origin my-topic-branch
```

**Second**, add the original repository as a new remote called upstream.

```
$ git remote add upstream git@github.com:jquery/jquery.git
```

**Third**, rollback your master to the upstream master.

```
$ git fetch upstream
$ git checkout master
$ git reset --hard upstream/master
$ git push --force-with-lease
```

Finally, delete the PR that you created off of `master`, and create a new PR off of `my-topic-branch`.

### Result

This would be the final state of affairs.

```
$ git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all -5

* abcd123 (origin/my-topic-branch, my-topic-branch) Your commit two
* abcd123 Your commit one
* abcd123 (HEAD -> master, upstream/master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Some jQuery commit
* abcd123 Some jQuery commit
* abcd123 Some jQuery commit
```